# Confusion with pronunciation in some words: 'm' and 'n' sounds when there is 'g'

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, phonetics

It has been bugging me for a while; I'm using memrise for learning and for example:

> - ちゅうごく China → I hear it pronounced chūmoku
> - かがく science → I hear it pronounced kanaku

Is this an error from memrise's side or are there rules for pronouncing some hiragana/katakana differently?

Comment: There are dialects of Japanese (fairly common ones) with what is often described as a nasal g sound. The topic has been extensively discussed. Here's an example. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/26227/the-nasal-allophones-of-g

Comment: So in standard japanese everything is read as it is written and it would be wrong to do so? (with few exceptions like particle ha for example)

Comment: Many people speak standard Japanese and also use a nasal g. Tokyo is a place where it is common. These things you heard are definitely not ちゅうもく or かなく. That is not an accurate way to describe what is being pronounced. Sorry if I'm being vague, the details are in the answer in the question I linked.

Comment: The nasal 'g' is an important feature of Standard Japanese.  Regardless of the region, professional announcers, singers, actors, voice actors are required to use it where necessary.  Japanese-learners often ask this question because they hear it and notice it in their audio materials for their Japanese study, anime, dramas, films, etc.  It is usually professionally trained people who record the materials, so the nasal 'g' is heard everywhere.  They often don't learn about it at all in Japanese courses, hence, the big confusion.

Comment: Are there any other rules for different pronounciation than nasal g? Or is it the only consonant that gets changed in pronounciation

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Probably you were hearing ["velar nasal g" [ŋ]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velar_nasal), which is an *allophone* of [g] mainly heard in eastern parts of Japan. In Japanese, [ŋ] and [g] in がぎぐげご are variants (allophones) of the same sound (phoneme), and most people are totally unaware of the difference. If you're not sure what I'm talking about, please read these first:

- [Why doesn't Japanese have a special Katakana form for "hu"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/16266/5010)
- [Why do Japanese speakers have difficulty pronouncing "L"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/8324/5010)

Many professional announcers, actors and vocalists still actively distinguish them depending on the place of がぎぐげご in a sentence. [This fact confuses some foreigners because they can easily notice different native Japanese speakers pronounce がぎぐげご differently](https://www.jref.com/forum/threads/my-g-pronunciation-woes.52084/). However, they are the same sounds to many average, untrained Japanese speakers like me. Even though you feel "m" or "n" sounds in が/ご, they're が/ご to Japanese ears. (Is your mother language English, by the way?) You'll have to get to used to them.

For more information, read [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_phonology#Weakening) on Wikipedia.

When you speak Japanese, it's totally fine to always stick to [g]. Some sources say 80% of the Japanese people do not use [ŋ] at all when they pronounce がぎぐげご in sentences. However, if you seriously want to be a professional announcer of Japanese, there are some rules you have to respect. See the linked article above.

Another example of consonant variation is [yotsugana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yotsugana). But remember that most Japanese people are totally unaware of this fact.

Comment: Such a neat answer, and no my native language is Croatian

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning (even though it is in the linked info) that the [ŋ] allophone is not usually used in the word-initial position. It usually only appears in the middle of words.