# Are フィ、ファ、フェ and フォ still pronounced with a bilabial fricative or just a normal English "f"?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology

I know that ふ is pronounced with a bilabial fricative, which is different from an English "f" or "h". However, in 外来語 there are some words containing things like フィ、ファ、フェ and フォ. e.g. フィクション. Seeing there is a ふ in there, I am wondering whether I should do a bilabial fricative or the English "f". Can Japanese people pronounce English "f"s?

Comment: In my experience: it depends. In general, as you probably know, 外来語 have a tendency to be pronounced with a nod to how they sound in the original language (especially in regard to word-ending vowels), but this varies by speaker, word, and context. So I would say I'm more likely to hear something closer to f than ɸ in the syllables you mention, but there's a lot of variation, and as a native English speaker I'm also hearing what I expect to hear. So I'm curious to hear what a native Japanese speaker says!

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/16266/5010

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both sounds are allophone and recognized as the same sound but English "f" sounds a foreign accent. Even if the speaker is familiar to English sound, s/he won't pronounce it with English "f" because 外来語 is Japanese.

Comment: In other words, the two sounds are a single phoneme and Japanese people will do a bilabial fricative instead of a labiodental fricative?

Comment: Yes, and that's how English spoken in Japanese accent sounds.