# How do you translate "Bavarian Bierkeller" into natural Japanese rendition? (and more)

Tags: translation, katakana, phrase-requests, nouns, formality

Here is what I think the translation of **Bavarian Bierkeller**:

> 1.**Bavarian** => **Bayerische** (German) = Of or relating to or characteristic of Bavaria or its people.
>
> **`バイエルン`**  (translated from German - ***Bayerische***) - Example: **Bavarian State Library​** = **`バイエルン州立図書館`**. **[Source](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%90%E3%82%A4%E3%82%A8%E3%83%AB%E3%83%B3%E5%B7%9E%E7%AB%8B%E5%9B%B3%E6%9B%B8%E9%A4%A8)**

or **`ババリア（人）の` ...** (translated from English, I suppose) - 
**`ババロア / ババリアの / ババリア人の`**

> 2. **Bierkeller** => **bier** + **keller** (*German*) => beer cellar (*English*)
>
> **`ビアケラー(パブ/バー)`  ** (literal translation and 'more **foreign** feeling').

Is it okay if I use pub here because in **[Oxford Dictonary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bierkeller)**, **bierkeller** means a bar or pub in Austria or Germany, especially in a basement.

Or should I use the *Japanese* version, **酒場** or **飲み屋** (**[source](https://jisho.org/search/pub)**):

```
ビアケラー(酒場/飲み屋)
```

### **Conclusion of `Bavarian Bierkeller` translation:**

Variants:

1.>**`バイエルンビアケラーパブ`**

2.>**ババリア(の) ビアケラーパブ`**

3.>**ババロアビアケラー酒場'**

4.>**ババロアビアケラー飲み屋'**

5.>**バイエルンビアケラー酒場'**

6.>**バイエルンビアケラー飲み屋'**

**Questions related as follows:**

> 1.Should I use the **katakana** from *German* or *English* or use the Japanese equivalent for faithful translation, or can I use both?
>
> 2.Is there any **guide** intended for faithful translation from various languages adapted into Japanese language and vice versa (especially English) that can be used for legal or official document translation in Japan? How do you know which is which?
>
> 3.Which of the six do you think is the best translation that fits naturally into the sentence provided?

**[Source 01](https://jisho.org/word/518697a5d5dda7b2c604c0af)**

The sentence context in question:

> The **Bavarian Bierkeller**, the best German beers served in two pint
>   steins, all brought ice cold to your table by waitresses in classic
>   **Bavarian** dress.

Thank you very much!

本当にありがとうございます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were the owner of such a pub, I would go with バイエルン・ビアケラー.

- ビアケラー酒場 and such is obviously tautological, and it sounds to me like a place where drink called ビアケラー is served. If the name ends with ビアケラー, people can guess it has something to do with beer, anyway. Actually there are some pubs named as ～ビアケラー in Japan. Alternatively, if you really need to be explicit about the fact that it's a pub, just give up using ビアケラー and use ビール酒場, ビアホール, ジャーマンパブ or such.
- Japanese people recognize that German state as バイエルン, not ババリア. So let's forget the "English" name. ババリアン is unsafe because it's very unfamiliar and sounds too close to "barbarian". (As you may know, the Japanese sound system does not distinguish [v] and [b] sounds).
- ババロア is also unsafe because it [specifically refers to Bavarian cream](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%90%E3%83%90%E3%83%AD%E3%82%A2). People would definitely mistake your pub as a sweets shop.

Comment: naruto, would you not include の? ->バイエルンのビアケラー?  or is the possessive の unnecessary for indicating nationality?  @Flonne Lightberry, about the name "Bavarian Bierkeller" is that the name of a specific shop, or are you talking about a general "type" of shop? The sentence provided for context doesn't make it 100% clear. (If it's a specific bar's name, then in English, the sentence would probably start with "**AT** the..." and the verb would be "**are** served")

Comment: @ericfromabeno I assumed this is a proper noun (the name of a certain shop) because it's capitalized and starts with "The". If that's the case, の is not necessary.

Comment: @ericfromabeno Yes, it's inspired from the specific shop. I am looking for a more general type of shop that people will understand once they read the 'signpost'.

Comment: @naruto Thanks for your answer! Anyway, regarding my second question and your answer, I think it can become a new question itself, how do Japanese differentiate between 'b' and 'v' in a context like Bavarian (the word 'B' and 'V' are used together in a Japanese word and can confuse non-linguist) - Bavarian vs Barbarian. So, I guess it's much better use the German-origin word, then.

Comment: they cannot distinguish b vs. v, l vs. r, f vs. h   .... They just cannot. when a Japanese person comes across a foreign word they have never studied before, which contains one or more of these sounds, they have to research the word, or just guess. There is NO way for them to know, **only** from katakana, which sound is "meant"

Comment: @FlonneLightberry Please read [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/16272/5010).

Comment: @ericfromabeno So, a normal Japanese who doesn't study/learn foreign language will not be able to differentiate B and V; R and L; F and H; E(ear) and E(bEar) or is it only older vs younger Japanese?

Comment: Japanese people are all generally aware of this issue, and they study hard to memorize standard words that might trip them up, but you still see professionally printed t-shirts and other clothes with "cool" English that has the wrong letter choice. It still amazes me that they don't use some kind of spell check before producing slogans etc...    Many Japanese people can HEAR the difference between these letter pairs, but still make the switching mistake when writing the words. It's all ages and all types of Japanese people that do this.