# 「卯月」 pronounced as 「うすき」(?)

Tags: pronunciation

In [a scene](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l9i2e2grbe0xor7/uduki.mp3?dl=0) from the Japanese movie 「[四月物語](https://www.wikiwand.com/ja/%E5%9B%9B%E6%9C%88%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E)」, the heroine introduced herself, saying 「[卯月]{うづき}です」, which is her given name.

The 「月」 part is kind of whispered (?) , and sounds to me more close to 「すき」.

I'm wondering how this line would sound to native Japanese speakers, e.g. will it be confused with 「すき」?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a native speaker, and this うづき was not confusing. The person clearly pronounced う-ず-き, although she was speaking in a mild whispering voice.

Note that "zu" and "dzu" are two [allophones](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/9333/5010) of ず/づ in Japanese, and "zu" tends to appear in the middle of a word. You may not hear a burst of air when ず/づ is pronounced in the middle of a word. Also note that most Japanese people pronounce ず and づ exactly the same way, although づ is sometimes romanized as "dzu" or "du". For details, see [/d, z/ neutralization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_phonology#/d,_z/_neutralization) and [Yotsugana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yotsugana).