# Listening, I mistake R for any of L, R or even D. Is there any exercise to improve my ability to hear this sound correctly?

Tags: pronunciation

I'm learning Japanese at an advanced age, and I'm having difficulty hearing R. Depending on the speaker, I hear one of three different consonants: R, or L but also it can sound like a D. In the first two cases, I know that it must be R, but when I mistake R for D, well, it can change the meaning. For example: I was pronouncing understood *waka**r**imashtia* as *waka**d**imashtia* because that's what I perceived. I've been replaying the lessons again and again, but I'm just not hearing it.

Is there any set of exercises or listening techniques, anything that helps?
Also, is this a common problem for older students?

*Addendum post comments:* I see from the related post that my problem is sort of the inverse of the issue therein but nonetheless a function of my own brain literally being stuck in English. And it seems time, practice, and perseverance are my only remedies. Thank you for your time and attention.

Comment: Do you speak North American English natively?

Comment: This seems off-topic to me as a resource/advice question.  Check our [resource topic on meta](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese).

Comment: @snailboat, yes, I do. I'm struggling in many ways; however, this worries me the most. If I can't hear it well then I'm starting from a huge disadvantage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do Japanese speakers have difficulty pronouncing "L"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/8324/why-do-japanese-speakers-have-difficulty-pronouncing-l)