# Is ホテルブレッド the name of a hotel?

Tags: translation

[image]Hello: I don't speak Japanese, so the only way for me to translate ホテルブレッド was using Google Translate, and "Hotel Bled" was the translation. Could someone please confirm if that's the correct translation? The words are printed on a snack label and it doesn't make sense to "name" a snack like that. Thank you !

Comment: Translation requests/confirmations are off-topic here, but anyway , "Hotel Bread". The characters in that name are just representations of the sounds of those English words (but there's no way to distinguish "bread" from "bled" using Japanese syllabaries, hence the translator's confusion). As to why it's called that, apparently this bread texture is associated with what is commonly served at a hotel? I dunno.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that translation is incorrect. This ブレッド is "bread", not "bled". The Japanese language [does not distinguish the L and R consonants](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/9333/5010). ホテルブレッド just means "hotel bread", and is the name of a kind of bread. I suppose it was so named because it is typically served at classy hotels. In general, it contains more butter and has richer taste than usual [食パン](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%A3%9F%E3%83%91%E3%83%B3).

Comment: Thank you so very much for your detailed explanations!